# How to obtain the new UDID for iPhones for registration with Apple portal

Tags: ios, xcode

When registering development devices with the Apple portal it used to be possible to get the UDID from iTunes. However now its changed from a UDID to an ECID.

Ok, just use the ECID I hear you say - but the UDID displayed in iTunes is much shorter than the ECID which appears in the portal if you plug in an iPhone directly to Xcode and let Xcode register it for you.

Previously UDID's used to be long, i.e.:

```
b8ec7cd40d738cc8d5a86b33655ffb1cb53ae628
```

But now they have changed, here's the UDID of a new device already registered in the Apple portal which was registered by Xcode automatically:

```
00008020-000D2D103604002E
```

And here's the ECID displayed for another device in iTunes:

```
D2D103604002E
```

The ECID is much shorter than the UDID that Xcode is using to register the device. So it would seem the ECID from iTunes can't be used as the UDID.
So where can I get the UDID from nowadays? (for those situations where its not possible to directly register the iPhone with the portal via Xcode).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this:

http://www.iphonehacks.com/2018/09/how-find-iphone-xs-max-udid.html

Haven't verified it works, but looks like it should. BUT it gets displayed like this:

> 00008020000D2D103604002E

So when registering with the portal, don't know if its going to be necessary to add a - to it, probably.